# Visual Studio 2008 TFS Shelve/Unshelve changes stopped working and hangs VS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, development-environment, shelve

Greetings.

This is second time I've actually spotted this problem with VS 2008 TS with TFS addon installed on top.

The problem is that **at some point, when you actively work with Shelve/Unshelve changes from TFS, the Shelve changes window** (when you hit "Shelve" button) **hangs** and hangs whole VS.

**After that, if you restart studio, the Shelve/Unshelve window just stops working.
Any attempt to call for Shelve/Unshelve window hangs Studio completely.**

Therefore, Shelving becomes unusable, but I really rely on this feature.

Anyone spotted this problem in practice? Any suggestion on fixing it?
(I've trying to reinstall VS and TFS completely right now and in addition cleaning registry for VS)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem fixed by taking a search in AppData folder of Windows for TFS cache entries.
Deleting TFS cache (which look like to be corrupted) helps in resolving this problem.

Comment: Also this resolved the issue in VS 2019 - clear the contents of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache`

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if TFS dialogs appear off-screen.  If pressing Esc "unfreezes" visual studio, this might be your problem.

I found the fix at: http://www.imiscommunity.com/visual_studio_2008_hangs_tfs_compare_dialog_not_visible

Comment: Awesome find Korey! Thanks. I were not able to verify this is the case, since I'm not using this functionality anymore.